# My variable is not being read after clearly defining it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a variable

```
var ownership_input = $("#result_ownership").text(convert($(this).val()));
```

then I reassign this variable to

```
var Ownership = ownership_input;
```

this would need to be the full code to understand the problem.

```
$(function(){
var Ownership = ownership_input; // this is a global variable

$("#ownership_factor").on('change',function() 
{
    $("#result_ownership").text(display($(this).val()));
    var ownership_input = $("#result_ownership").text(convert($(this).val()));
}
```

I am thinking this is because the `ownership_input` is inside the on change function.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Declared with `var` inside the "change" handler, it is **not** a global variable.

Comment: `ownership_input` is in a different scope than `Ownership`

Comment: how can I bring ownership_input out of the change handler so the rest of the script can see ownership_input

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning your `ownership_input` before it's declared. You can directly assign to `Ownership`:

```
$(function(){
   var Ownership;
   $("#ownership_factor").on('change',function() {
       $("#result_ownership").text(display($(this).val()));
       Ownership = $("#result_ownership").text(convert($(this).val()));
   }
}
```